# How to write a program in c# that outputs 2 numbers and they must not be equal?

Tags: c#

I need to write a program that outputs 2 numbers, but they must not be equal.
This is the code I came up with but it's wrong, sometimes it still outputs the same numbers. 
Can somebody help me to solve this problem?
Thanks.

The code:

```
        string a = null;
        string b = null;
        bool same = false;
        Random rn = new Random();
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        {
            a = rn.Next(1, 3).ToString();
            if (a == b)
            {
                same = true;
                while (same == true)
                {
                    if (a == b)
                    {
                        a = rn.Next(1, 3).ToString();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        same = false;
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Second number is: " + a);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" First number is: " + a);
                b = a;
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Maybe keep trying until you find a number that's different, instead of giving up immediately? Think about what `j < 2` means in your loop: The loop continues *only as long as `j` is less than `2`*. Is that long enough? Maybe stick a breakpoint in there and step through the loop in the debugger, one line at a time, and see what it's really doing.

Comment: Do learn about [`do while` loops](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_do_while_loop.htm)!

Comment: Also consider comparing numbers to numbers instead of strings.

Comment: `do a = rnd.Next(..); while (a==b);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
    string a = null;
    string b = null;
    Random rn = new Random();
    a = rn.Next(1, 3).ToString();
    do {
        b = rn.Next(1, 3).ToString();
       }while ( a==b)

   Console.WriteLine("Second number is: " + b)
   Console.WriteLine(" First number is: " + a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Surely you must have more requirements than you've listed (otherwise just pick a random for one of them and add one to it for the second number), but something like this springs to mind:

```
Random rnd = new Random();    

// Pick two random numbers between 1 and 2, inclusive
int first = rnd.Next(1, 3);
int second = rnd.Next(1, 3);

// Continue to pick a second number as long as it's equal to the first one
while (first == second)
{
    second = rnd.Next(1, 3);
}

// Output the results
Console.WriteLine($"First number is: {first}");
Console.WriteLine($"Second number is: {second}");
Console.ReadLine();
```